# What's the difference between 할 수 있다 and 할 수 있어?

Tags: grammar, phrases

I don't get the difference between 할 수 있다 and 할 수 있어. (다 and 어). I want to write ‘I can do it’.
I want to do a tattoo but I don't know which one is proper one?

Comment: 할수있다(formal use) 할수있어(informal)

Answer (score 1):

-다 and -어 have lots of cases.

-다 is formal one
-어 is informal one.

When u talking with people, it is more natural to speak '나는 할 수 있어'.
However, When u write for letters or books, it would be more natural to speak '나는 할 수 있다'

Simply speaking,

나는 할 수 있다  (-다) => It describes the states, facts of some situations.
나는 할 수 있어  (-어) => It is more like colloquial style.

Answer (score 0):

As the others have explained, the difference is formality. Since it's almost unheard of for Koreans to get a 한글 tattoo, it's hard to say which one would be more natural.

Answer (score 0):

you can use '어' for question sentence, too.

너는 할 수 있어? is you can this?
but
너는 할 수 있다? is weird.